# I want to receive an email when an item goes back in stock

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to have BeautifulSoup check these webpages, I threw in one more item that is in stock at the end to simulate when they would come in stock. It is having an issue when it comes to that and throwing an error. I am wanting it to either 1) find something else on that page and not throw the error, or 2) if it throws the error I will then know the "Sold Out" is not there and then if thats the case I want it to email me something simple like check this url for the instock item

```
import smtplib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import smtplib

url = [url1,url2,url3,url4]
data = []
for pg in url:
    page = requests.get(pg)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    soldout = soup.find_all(text="Sold Out")
    parent = soldout[0].parent
    cart = soup.find_all(text="Add to cart")
    print(parent.string)

else:

    gmail_user = 'email'
    gmail_password = 'password'

    sent_from = gmail_user
    to = ['my email']
    subject = 'Item is in stock'
    body = 'link to in stock item'

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:
    smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    smtp_server.ehlo()
    smtp_server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    smtp_server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    smtp_server.close()
    print("Email sent successfully!")
except Exception as ex:
    print("Something went wrong….", ex)
```

Here is the program running with the error:

```
Sold Out
Sold Out
Sold Out
Sold Out
Sold Out
Sold Out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 19, in <module>
    parent = soldout[0].parent
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: _It is having an issue when it comes to that and throwing an error_ Are we supposed to guess what the error is?  Update the question to include the error traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more code and update your question with the traceback message and the specific errors you encountered. Maybe also add the website you are trying to scrape.

However, checking inventory in a website is a pretty straightforward process. Consider the following:

- Add the item to a cart (normally done via a POST request, check with the browser's network tab)
- Check if the item was added successfuly to the cart (evaluate the
  response for the previous request, error messages should appear if the item is not available)

You could, in theory, add thousands of items to the cart and check if the website
allows it. If you encounter an error, lower the item's quantity until the item
is added. That way you can know the total number of items in stock,
instead of just knowing there is one item available.

Comment: I updated the code to include the error. The problem I have is the items are very very rarely in stock, so I can not add it to cart and have issues inspecting it to see what the difference is, only that the "Sold Out" goes away,

Comment: Sorry, let me add that i was having issues when the item wouldnt appear when it was out of stock on the search field. But what I did was find the url of each item that goes out of stock and that is what im searching "Sold Out" for